# 2X2 Overshadowing Image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a webpage that allows the 2x2 of image blocks, when hovered over, to overshadow the other images that are in the body.

But for some reason I cannot get the image to escape its own div box.

```
html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    div {
        width: 50%;
        height: 50%;
        float: left;
        position: relative;
        transition: width 2s, height 4s;
        transition-delay: 2s;
    }
    div:hover {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%}

    div:nth-of-type(1) {
        background: #ccc;
    }

    div:nth-of-type(2) {
        background: #bbb;
        border-left: 1px solid #f00;
    }

    div:nth-of-type(3) {
        background: #aaa;
        border-top: 1px solid #f00;
    }
    div:nth-of-type(4) {
        background: #ddd;
        border-top: 1px solid #f00;
        border-left: 1px solid #f00;
    }

    <body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for an effect something like this:

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}
body {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 49%;
  height: 25%;
  position: relative;
  transition: width 2s, height 4s;
  transition-delay: 2s;
}

div:hover {
  z-index: 100;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: #eee;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: #bbb;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: #999;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background: #666;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, you're looking into a hover option that'll cast a shadow layer on top of everything else?

If so, there's a simple trick to that, using the `transform: scale(1)` and the `box-shadow` command.
Personally I prefer to insert all images into separate DIVs and assign a class to them.

Try this:

https://codepen.io/meta704/pen/LYpREjK

Comment: but I did that but it doesn't, hover over will box-shadow

Comment: I want to bring it over the other pictures

Comment: You can use a lightbox.
OR you could use javascript to fill the parent div ("container") with the hovered image